# Can I implement/put an array on a switch conditional?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was building my code when came to my mind a bizarre idea, can I implement/put an array inside a switch?

I mean, how can I make the `codeHide` *case* work? with this piece of code it don't work.

When I ask to set the command and I put `hide()` (that is `codeHide[0]` on the `codeHide` array) I want to `switch` take the `codeHide` case (my if-statement) and return an `alert` telling me the `alertMessage` of that particular array element.

If I put `hide(background)` (that is `codeHide[1]` on the `codeHide` array) I want to switch take the `codeHide` case else (of my if-statement) and return an `alert` telling me the `alertMessage` of that particular array element(in the is-statement).

Hope you understand me.

Doing this it don't work and I think it's because the "`case codeHide:`".

And this is what I've done so far:

```
var codeHide = ['hide()', 'hide(background)'];

$(".code").on("click", function () {
    var codePrompt = prompt("Set the code in the command line."),
    alertMessage = "",
    consoleMessage = "Used '" + codePrompt + "' command.";

switch (codePrompt) {
    case codeHide:
        if (codeHide[0]) {
            alertMessage = "Hiding elements...";
        } else {
            alertMessage = "Hiding Background...";
        }
        break;
    default:
        alertMessage = consoleMessage = "We are sorry but you entered a WRONG command, try again tho!\ntyped: " + codePrompt;
        break;
    }
    alert(alertMessage);
    console.log(consoleMessage);
});
```

Comment: you should be able to do a case codeHide[0], case codeHide[1] etc... if that's what you're asking

Comment: alertMessage=["a","b","c"][prompt('enter 0-2')] || "default" ; replaces your whole switch logic and runs faster than switch. use an object over a switch anytime you need to turn just one thing into just one other thing from a list of things that have a direct relationship.

Comment: @dadavis is not that what I was asking but thx anyway.

Comment: You should declare codeHide like this `var codeHide = {"hide()": "Hiding elements...", "hide(background)": "Hiding Background..."};`, then just do this `alertMessage = codeHide[codePrompt] ? codeHide[codePrompt] : "We are sorry but you entered a WRONG command, try again tho!\ntyped: " + codePrompt;`

Comment: a shorter version of the ternary results can use defaults: alertMessage = codeHide[codePrompt] ||  "We are sorry but you entered a WRONG command, try again tho!\ntyped: " + codePrompt;

Comment: note that the internal logic of `switch` is very similar to maping  between `key` and `value` in some look-up ... @dandavis ah good point, forgot that, although I know about that use in script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`switch` operates by comparing the value being switched on to each of the possible cases using the identity operator `===`. This means that you can put an array inside a `case`, and it will work as specified (but certainly not very intuitively for arrays):

```
var x = [1];
var a = [1];

switch (x) {
    case [1]: alert("it's [1]!"); break;
    case a: alert("it's a!"); break;
    case x: alert("it's x!"); break;
}
```

This will alert "it's x!", while you might be expecting that either of the preceding two cases would be "good enough" to trigger. But that's just how `===` works:

```
[1] === x   // false
a === x     // true
x === x     // true
```

So while you can technically use an array, in practice it would be very unusual to have a situation where it's actually useful to do so.

Going back to your code, since the values you are interested in are strings it seems that using a simple object as a map would do just fine:

```
var commands = {
    "hide()": {
        alert: "Hiding elements...",
        console: "Blah blah"
    }.
    "hide(background)": {
        alert: "Hiding background...",
        console: "Blah blah"
    }.
};
var fallback = {
    alert: "Sorry, wrong command",
    console: "Sorry, wrong command"
};
```

which would then allow you to write

```
var result = commands[input] || fallback;
alert(result.alert);
console.log(result.console);
```

Comment: Thx mate, but I'm a bit noob at javascript and I'm not there yet. I'll keep that tho!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying something like

```
var commands = {
    hide: 'hide()',
    hideBg: 'hide(background)'
};

var codePrompt = prompt("Set the code in the command line."),
    alertMessage;

switch (codePrompt) {
    case commands.hide:
        alertMessage = "Hiding elements...";
        break;
    case commands.hideBg:
        alertMessage = "Hiding Background...";
        break;
    default:
        alertMessage = "WRONG command";
        break;
    }
}
```

However, you can also use

```
var commands = {
    'hide()': "Hiding elements...",
    'hide(background)': "Hiding Background..."
};

var codePrompt = prompt("Set the code in the command line.");

var alertMessage = commands[codePrompt] || "WRONG command";
```

I guess you also want to run some functions:

```
var commands = {
    'hide()': {
        text: "Hiding elements...",
        funcion: someFunctionToHide
    },
    'hide(background)': {
        text: "Hiding Background...",
        funcion: someFunctionToHideBackground
    }
};

var codePrompt = prompt("Set the code in the command line."),
    command = commands[codePrompt];

if(!command) {
    alertMessage = "WRONG command";
} else {
    alertMessage = command.text;
    command.function();
}
```

Comment: Thx mate, this helps me a lot! and is not too difficult to understand. Ops!, I think yo made a little mistake at the first code piece( second line just after " 'hide(background)' " you put a "]".